# How can I adjust query timeouts

Tags: skyve

I'm getting a timeout exception in my local dev environment for a Persistence SQL query.
Is the timeout configurable in Skyve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 global timeouts in specified in the json config
eg

```
    // Datastore definitions
    "dataStores": {
        // Skyve data store
        "skyve": {
            // JNDI name
            "jndi": "java:/H2Demo", 
            // Dialect
            "dialect": "org.skyve.impl.persistence.hibernate.dialect.H2SpatialDialect",
            // Timeout for data store connections employed in general UI/forms processing - 0 indicates no timeout
            "oltpConnectionTimeoutInSeconds": 30,
            // Timeout for data store connections employed when running jobs and background tasks - 0 indicates no timeout
            "asyncConnectionTimeoutInSeconds": 300
        }
    },
```

There are timeouts you can specify against each metadata query.

eg

```
        <query name="qUsers" documentName="User" timeoutInSeconds="23">
```

All programmatic queries can set the timeout.

eg

```
    Persistence p = CORE.getPersistence();
    SQL sql = p.newSQL("select 1 ADM_Contact");
    sql.setTimeoutInSeconds(200);
    sql.scalarIterable(Number.class);
```

```
    p.newSQL("select 1 ADM_Contact").noTimeout().scalarResults(Number.class);
```